# Odd step in derivation of phasor Telegrapher's equations

Tags: electromagnetism, phasor

In the derivation of the phasor form of the Telegrapher's equations (in "Fundamentals of Applied Electromagentics" by Ulaby), there is a step I'm not following:[image: question]

When going between eq. 2.16 and eq. 2.18a, why does the complex exponential disappear when taking the derivative of the V and I phasors? Since the derivative is being performed with respect to z and the complex exponential being defined in terms of t, shouldn't it remain after that derivative as a constant (and only the exponential would remain)? If being used as a function, wouldn't the product rule would leave a cosine and its derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equations 2.17 are in time domain.  e^(j*w*t) is the representation of a sinusoid in the time domain.

Equations 2.18 are in the phasor domain.  In the phasor domain, the sinusoid is assumed - a phasor represents the amplitude and phase of a sinusoid, but a phasor is NOT a function of time and thus does not include a time domain represenation of a sinusoid.

I have borrowed from wikipedia below:  The equation in blue is the time domain representation - notice the dependence on both frequency (w) and time (t).  The red box shows the equivalent phasor form - notice that both frequency and time are missing.  A phasor is only valid at a single frequency, and that frequency is typically inferred from context.

[image]

Comment: So just to make sure I fully grasp this mathematically, you're saying the Fourier transform would cancel out a complex exponential in the time domain? From transform pairs, I thought including that exponential meant a frequency difference in the frequency domain.